# Using regex to not match periods between numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a regex code that splits strings between `[.!?]`, and it works, but I'm trying to add something else to the regex code. I'm trying to make it so that it doesn't match `[.]` that's between numbers. Is that possible? So, like the example below:

```
$input = "one.two!three?4.000.";
$inputX = preg_split("~(?>[.!?]+)\K(?!$)~", $input); 

print_r($inputX);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => one. [1] => two! [2] => three? [3] => 4. [4] => 000. )
```

**Need Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => one. [1] => two! [2] => three? [3] => 4.000. )
```

Comment: Do you realy have a dot in 4.000? Is there a minimum of chars between between `[.!?]`?

Comment: @bodruk Um. The dot is between 4 and 0? You even typed it: 4.000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to split on this:

```
(?<=(?<!\d(?=[.!?]+\d))[.!?])(?![.!?]|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/kQ6zO4/1

It uses lookarounds to determine where to split.  It looks behind to try to match anything in the set `[.!?]` *one or more times* as long as it isn't preceded by *and* succeeded by a digit.

It also won't return the last empty match by ensuring the last set isn't the end of the string.

**UPDATE:**

This should be much more efficient actually:

```
(?!\d+\.\d+).+?[.!?]+\K(?!$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/eN7rS8/1

Here is another possibility using regex `flags`:

```
$input = "one.two!three???4.000.";
$inputX = preg_split("~(\d+\.\d+[.!?]+|.*?[.!?]+)~", $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

print_r($inputX);
```

It includes the delimiter in the split and ignores empty matches.  The regex can be simplified to `((?:\d+\.\d+|.*?)[.!?]+)`, but I think what is in the code sample above is more efficient.

Comment: Oh no. The string can start or end with a digit. Just not surrounded by BOTH sides with digits.

Comment: It works, but on my original regex, if there was something like this: $input = "one.two!?!!three?4.000."; with extra !?...! between words, it doesn't include them in the array. So the array would contain, two!?!! as oppose to  two ! ? ! ! in different indexes.

Comment: Right now, it would look something like this Array ( [0] => one. [1] => two! [2] => ? [3] => ! [4] => ! [5] => three? [6] => 4.000. )

Comment: As oppose to something like this Array ( [0] => one. [1] => two!?!! [5] => three? [6] => 4.000. )

Comment: Yes. This is awesome. Thanks, buddy.

Comment: An other efficient approach consists to build a pattern for `preg_match_all` that doesn't allow gaps: https://regex101.com/r/aF3kA8/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Nice, that is efficient.  Thanks for the info.